# Magnolia REST API

Tags: rest, magnolia

Is there any way to request Magnolia REST API for list of products
which could be retrieved with equivalent of JCR SQL2

```
select * from [mgnl:product] where productName like '%Nikon%'
```

If it's only possible with custom rest end-point could you please point to tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use content delivery endpoint to do so. Syntax is like: `GET /delivery/{endpoint-prefix}/v1?key1=value1&key2=value2`
 See https://git.magnolia-cms.com/projects/MODULES/repos/rest/browse/magnolia-rest-content-delivery for more details.

Comment: Thank you! Very useful link.

Comment: How I can pass List of node types to exclude in excludeNodeTypes? I mean syntax of that "list" in curl  command...

Answer (score 5):

**Update as of Magnolia REST 2.1**, using the v2 endpoint definition:

To answer the second question about node-types, here's what it looks like, as a YAML file in a light module, *e.g.* `<module-name>/restEndpoints/delivery/my-products_v1.yaml`:

```yaml
class: info.magnolia.rest.delivery.jcr.v2.JcrDeliveryEndpointDefinition
workspace: products
rootPath: /
includeSystemProperties: false
bypassWorkspaceAcls: true
depth: 2
nodeTypes:
  - mgnl:product
childNodeTypes:
  - mgnl:contentNode
```

The [Delivery endpoint](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS56/Delivery+endpoint+API) config takes node-types to *include*.

- `nodeTypes` specify the primary list of JCR node types to query—in your case `mgnl:product`;
- `childNodeTypes` specify which child-nodes to include as JSON objects *under* the primary results, when `depth` is greater than 0.

With the above configuration, you may run the following requests to query products or get a single product, respectively:

- `GET <host>/.rest/delivery/my-products/v1?productName[like]=%25Nikon%25`
- `GET <host>/.rest/delivery/my-products/v1/path/to/Nikon-1`

This differs from Magnolia's former [Nodes endpoint](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS56/Nodes+endpoint+API), which is not configurable, but only lets consumers *exclude* node-types.